# Limit the number of edges can be added to a vertex in orientDB

Tags: orientdb

I am using orientDB 2.2.7 via Java API and have created the following vertexes:

```
Vertex Car
Vertex Driver
Edge Co-Owner
```

For each car it can only get a maximum of five owners, I have managed to do that by code in a trivial way, my question is there any mechanism in orientDB that can limit the number of edges of type co-owner can be added to vertex car?

Comment: Hello, I don't think there's such a feature in OrientDB, BUT you could write a server side JS function that you'll call from your java application

Comment: Or maybe this could be usefull http://orientdb.com/docs/master/Hook.html

Answer (score 2):

I made this little test case using [Dynamic Hooks](http://orientdb.com/docs/master/Dynamic-Hooks.html), I hope is similar to yours.

```sql
create class Car extends V
create class Driver extends V
create class CoOwner extends E,OTriggered

ALTER CLASS CoOwner CUSTOM onBeforeCreate=createOwner

create property Car.ID string
create property Car.Model string
create property Car.Color string

create property Driver.Name string
create property Driver.Surname string
create property Driver.CF string

create index Car.ID UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX
create index Driver.CF UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX
```

---

```sql
create vertex Car set ID="AA666ZZ", Model="Fiat Panda", Color="Black"
create vertex Car set ID="BB222ZZ", Model="Ferrari 458 Italia", Color="Red"
create vertex Car set ID="CC954ZZ", Model="AlfaRomeo Giulietta", Color="Blue"

create vertex Driver set Name="Pino", Surname="Pasticcino", CF="PNOPSC1234567890"
create vertex Driver set Name="Giannaldo", Surname="Pippi", CF="GNLPIP1234567890"
create vertex Driver set Name="Pierromeo", Surname="Pasticcino", CF="PRMPSC1234567890"
create vertex Driver set Name="Adalbrigo", Surname="Brighi", CF="ALRBGH1234567890"
create vertex Driver set Name="Renfrancesco", Surname="Raldi", CF="RFCRLD1234567890"
create vertex Driver set Name="Caldanzio", Surname="Freddi", CF="CDZFRD1234567890"
create vertex Driver set Name="Roberdrigo", Surname="Brighi", CF="RBRBGH1234567890"
create vertex Driver set Name="Gorzorg", Surname="Il Distruggitore", CF="GRZIDG1234567890"
```

---

then you need to create a JS function with the following code:

```js
var MAX_EDGES = 5;
var CUR_EDGES = doc.field('out').field('out_CoOwner').size();

print('\n--------------------------------------------------------------------');
print('\n\nMax Edges: ' + MAX_EDGES);
print('\nCoOwner edges: ' + CUR_EDGES);

if ( CUR_EDGES > MAX_EDGES ){
  throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("Maximum number of edges reached.");
}
else {
  print('OK!');
}
```

---

then you can test it by trying to add 6 edges.

```sql
create edge CoOwner from (select from Car where ID = "AA666ZZ") to (select from Driver where CF = "PNOPSC1234567890")
create edge CoOwner from (select from Car where ID = "AA666ZZ") to (select from Driver where CF = "RFCRLD1234567890")
create edge CoOwner from (select from Car where ID = "AA666ZZ") to (select from Driver where CF = "GNLPIP1234567890")
create edge CoOwner from (select from Car where ID = "AA666ZZ") to (select from Driver where CF = "CDZFRD1234567890")
create edge CoOwner from (select from Car where ID = "AA666ZZ") to (select from Driver where CF = "PRMPSC1234567890")
create edge CoOwner from (select from Car where ID = "AA666ZZ") to (select from Driver where CF = "RBRBGH1234567890")
```

console log:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------


Max Edges: 5

CoOwner edges: 1
OK!

--------------------------------------------------------------------


Max Edges: 5

CoOwner edges: 2
OK!

--------------------------------------------------------------------


Max Edges: 5

CoOwner edges: 3
OK!

--------------------------------------------------------------------


Max Edges: 5

CoOwner edges: 4
OK!

--------------------------------------------------------------------


Max Edges: 5

CoOwner edges: 5
OK!

--------------------------------------------------------------------


Max Edges: 5

CoOwner edges: 6

2016-08-22 17:46:45:292 SEVER Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OCommandScriptException: Error on parsing script at position #2: Error on execution of the script
Script: createOwner
-------^
    DB name="stack39062533"
--> javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Maximum number of edges reached. in <eval> at line number 10 at column number 2
--> <eval>:10:2 java.lang.RuntimeException: Maximum number of edges reached.
--> java.lang.RuntimeException: Maximum number of edges reached. [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is great, but my question is how to do it with Java API, because the limitation is business side rather than code side so user can change it without writing code, i will check java hooks, again thank you