# OrientDB: Abort Update Statement inside Hook

Tags: orientdb

is it possible to abort or undo an OrientDB Statement as

UPDATE time SET name = 'Jason' WHERE surname = 'Miner';

inside Hooks like

```
 public RESULT onRecordBeforeUpdate(ODocument iDocument) {
     return ORecordHook.RESULT.RECORD_NOT_CHANGED;
 }

 public void onRecordAfterUpdate(ODocument iDocument) {
 }
```

I tried a lot of things as undo, clear, reload and so on. Nevertheless the name is updated everytime in the database.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What you want to do is not to update the name if the name is already Jason and the  surname Milner ?

Comment: Yes, for instance 'do not update name if surname is Miner', otherwise update is OK.

Comment: WDYT about checking whether surname is 'Miner' and in that case throw an exception? Take a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062533/limit-the-number-of-edges-can-be-added-to-a-vertex-in-orientdb/39083794#39083794) example (it's in javascript but the logic should work anyway).  Ivan